# 5 distinct dice results in 6 rolls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

[image]

Given we have rolls 6 iid dice, what are the odds of having 5 distinct rolls (where we have defined $N$ as the number of distinct outcomes)?

The work above is my professor's provided solution, but I don't think it's right? It's equivalent to $6!/6^6$, which would be equivalent to a situation where all the dice rolls are distinct? This can't just be a coincidence.

The way I pictured doing it was like so:

$$(6/6)(5/6)(4/6)(3/6)(2/6)(5/6)$$

where the first 5 terms are the 5 distinct dice rolls, and the last one is $5/6$ because it must be one of those distinct rolls. This gives me an answer of $0.077$. However, I don't think this is right because it doesn't account for the fact that the 2 non-unique outcomes can be placed in different positions among the 6 roll (6 choose 2 times actually).

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the probability for selecting five distinct results when rolling six regular dice.

$\binom 65 5!/6^6$ counts the ways to select five from six results and then arrange them; against the ways to roll six six-sided die.   That's not right at all.   It is missing out on counting a sixth die, and its value and location.

---

You have $\frac 6 6\frac 5 6\frac 4 6\frac 3 6\frac 2 6\frac 5 6$, which is the probability of rolling 5 distinct results on 5 dice then repeating one of those results with the sixth dice.   That's close, *however*, you don't require the repeated result to be in any particular place, and you want to select a place for it without over counting.

Well, $\frac 6 6\frac 5 6\frac 4 6\frac 3 6$ is the probability of rolling a sequence of four distinct results, and $\frac 2 6\frac 1 6$ is the probability of rolling a fifth distinct result, twice.   Finally $\binom 62$ counts the ways to merge these two sequences into one.

$$\frac{6!/2!}{6^4}\cdot\frac{2!}{6^2}\cdot\frac{6!}{4!\,2!}=\frac{25}{108}$$

---

I'd count the ways to select dice to be a double and four singleton results, and ways to select the results for them from the six faces (1 for the double, 4 for the singles, and 1 not used); against ways to make a sequence of six choices with six independent options.

$$\dfrac{\binom{6}{2,1,1,1,1}\binom 6{1,4,1}}{6^6} = \dfrac{\frac{6!}{2!}\frac{6!}{4!}}{6^6} =\frac{25}{108}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just wondering, but is there any way you could lead me to the same answer you got from my approach? It seems that (my answer)*3 = yours, so I'm just wondering if there's some obvious factor of 3 that I'm missing (I kinda understand my approach more too)

Comment: @Anthony Does that help?

Comment: Yup that helps! Thanks!

Comment: I am not familiar with the binomial coefficient syntax where you have more than 1 number for the lower value. Is it actually a binomial coefficient? The evaluations seem to be more aligned with the formula for permutations with repeated numbers.

Comment: @user5965026 It is called a **multinomial coefficient**.  It is the same principle, just more factors in the denominator.$$\dbinom {a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k}{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k}=\dfrac{(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k)!}{a_1!\cdot a_2!\cdot\cdots\cdot a_k!}$$ So $\tbinom 6{1,4,1}=\tfrac{6!}{1!~4!~1!}$ et cetera...

Comment: Ah I see. So I just want to rephrase to confirm my understanding. $\binom{6}{2,1,1,1}$ is the number of permutations (or number of ways to arrange) of $\{A,B,C,D,E,E\}$ where $A,B,C,D,E$ correspond to distinct numbers from 1-6. $\binom{6}{1,4,1}$ is the number of combinations that we can choose from 6 different numbers such that we have 5 distinct values, with exactly 1 of the values repeated once?

Comment: Also, there are several places with 6's here in your answer, but they represent 2 distinct things, and I want to make sure I understand what they represent. So if have an $N$-sided die, and we roll it $M$ times, (where $N=M=6$), then your solution can be symbolically written as
$$
\frac{\binom{M}{4,1,1,1,1}\binom{N}{1,4,1}}{N^M}
$$

Perhaps I shouldn't say symbolically because I do not believe this expression is valid if $N \neq 6$ and/or $M \neq 6$, but I am just trying to make sure I understand what each 6 is representing with the symbols.

Comment: @user5965026 As indicated by the paragraph: $\binom 6{2,1,1,1, 1}$ counts the ways to select **placement** : the arrangement of *dice* where a double and four distinct singletons will appear.  $\binom 6{1,4,1}$ counts the ways to select the **results** for those dice: one from four *faces* for the double, and four from five (remaining) *faces* for the singletons, (with one face not appearing).

Answer (score 3):

Your professor's attempt of $\cfrac{\binom{6}{5}\cdot5!}{6^6}$ is almost correct, by a factor of 15: the answer is 
$$\cfrac{\binom{6}{5}\cdot5\cdot\frac{6!}{2}}{6^6}.$$

Here's how: choose five distinct dice rolls from six, and designate one of the just chosen five to appear twice. Arrange the six numbers, with one repeated, in $\frac{6!}{2!}$ ways.